# Chart.js making this chart more readable / scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, chart.js

I'm using chart.js to generate this stacked graph. The problem is, the chart is too small and the users won't be able to read the chart (the stacked portion is really important, some of the tooltips on the X axis are missing (the dataset is a bit large). I want the chart to occupy a very specific place within my webpage.

Is there a way to make the scale on the X-axis smaller and simply being able to horizontally scroll through chart?

```js
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    const data = {
        labels: {{ labels | safe }},
        datasets: {{ data_list | safe}}
    };
    const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
        plugins: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked'
        },
        },
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{ 
            stacked: true,
            }],
          yAxes: [{ 
            stacked: true,
            }],
        },
    }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
      var ctx = document.getElementById('pie-chart-stacked').getContext('2d');
      window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };
  </script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Project Scanner</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Project Scanner">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/home.css' %}">

</head>

<body>
      <div id="container" style="width: 50%;">
        <canvas id="pie-chart-stacked"></canvas>
      </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Also here's a picture of the chart in it's current state:
[image: Unreadable chart.js chart]

EDIT: Added a new picture of the chart with a smaller dataset.

[image: Chart.js chart with a smaller dataset]

Comment: Could you use Zoom in / out to show a portion of the chart ?

Comment: @LahEzcen Not sure if I can but I can add a picture of what I'd like for the chart to look like using a smaller dataset. I'll edit my answer with the picture, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chart.js doesn't support scrollable `axis` natively. ChartJs charts are responsive and change width according to parent container. You can do something like this :

```
<div class="chartWrapper">
  <div class="chartAreaWrapper">
    <canvas id="chart" height="400" width="15000"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.chartWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.chartWrapper > canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.chartAreaWrapper {
  width: 15000px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Finally, add this options object to your chart

```
options: {     
  scales: { 
  xAxes: [{   
    ticks: {
      padding: 20
    }
  }]
}}
```

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/example/javascript/chart.js/create-a-horizontal-scrolling-chartjs-line-chart-with-a-locked-y-axis.html) is one more example on how you can make your chart scrollable

Answer (score 0):

try the responsive chart options.
responsive: [{
breakpoint: 769,
bar: {
horizontal: false
},

Comment: I'm assuming you mean like this:       options: {
        responsive: {
          breakpoint: 769,
          bar: {
            horizontal: false
          },
          }
      }
I added your line but it didn't change anything